# Load a grib2 file in Python

Tags: python, grib, python-xarray

I am trying to load grib2 files and I am not sure if the files are the issues or if the way I am trying to load them.

The files are extracted from [here](ftp://ftpprd.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/cfs/prod/cfs) (I didn't download them from here, but copied them from a folder of a colleague that gets them from here - so really they should be the same files..., but I then also tried to insert the ftp address and got the same errors).

I tired `pygrib`

```
grbs = pygrib.open('pgbf2016060100.01.2016053100.grib2')
```

gets this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-674763ffdd1f> in <module>()
----> 1 grbs = pygrib.open('pgbf2016060100.01.2016053100.grib2')

pygrib.pyx in pygrib.open.__cinit__ (pygrib.c:2772)()

IOError: [Errno could not open %s] pgbf2016060100.01.2016053100.grib2
```

I tried `xarray`

```
ds = xr.open_dataset("pgbf2016060100.01.2016053100.grb2",engine='pynio')
```

and I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/software/centos6/x86_64/canopy-1.5.2/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_code(self, code_obj, result)
   3081             if result is not None:
   3082                 result.error_in_exec = sys.exc_info()[1]
-> 3083             self.showtraceback()
   3084         else:
   3085             outflag = 0

/software/centos6/x86_64/canopy-1.5.2/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple,     filename, tb_offset, exception_only)
   1858                 return
   1859 
-> 1860             if issubclass(etype, SyntaxError):
   1861                 # Though this won't be called by syntax errors in the input
   1862                 # line, there may be SyntaxError cases with imported code.

TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

I tried directly `NIO`

```
f = nio.open_file("pgbf2016060100.01.2016053100.grb2")
```

and I get the same error as the one from `xarray`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check integrity of your file by wgrib2. And check pygrib configuration files, may be grib2 support had been turn off during installation, because pygrib use grib_api and it is possible to compile grib_api library without grib2 support.

Answer (score 1):

I Had this problem with `pygrib`. The root of the problem is the `JPEG` support, something was wrong with `openjpeg` or `jasper` libraries, after o many tries, I made this steps to solve this problem with the pygrib reinstalling:

- Remove this libraries with:

  `yum remove openjpeg` and `yum remove jasper` (I use RHEL 7)
- After reinstalling this libraries with:

  `yum install openjpeg` and `yum install jasper`
- Make sure of `grib_api` or his replacement `eccodes` are no longer installed. After, install `eccodes` from the source, follow this [instructions](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/ecCodes+installation). The installation directory is vital for the next step, in my case I installed it in `/usr/local/lib/eccodes` (I make an empty directory called `eccodes` in `/usr/local/lib`), this directory are specify during the `cmake` with the argument `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/where/you/install/eccodes`.
- Finally install `pygrib` from the source following this [steps](https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib/blob/master/README.md), I only uncomment the line 15 in the `setup.cfg` and setting  `grib_api_dir = /usr/local/lib/eccodes` (Here are the importance of the install directory). If the installation pass without problems the `test.py` the problem is already solved.

Comment: Thanks! I left pygrib behind for xarray, but by any chance did you open a PR on the GitHub repo? it seems relevant. thanks!

Comment: Not, I didn't open a pull request on the GitHub repository. This error is maybe for an issue in the installation of `openjpeg` or `jasper`. I will try to use `xarray`,  looks awesome and simply. Thanks!